# Updating database data in mysql database using netbeans

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I create Computer laboratory Inventory System and i'm going to update the data in the monitor list. I have monitor list in JtabbedPane and it has subtabbedPane name Laboratory A, Laboratory B,Laboratory C, Laboratory D, Laboratory E, Library. When I select item data in SubtabbedPane Laboratory A, the selected item will not place to the JtextFields in the monitor entry and when i'm click the Update button i got error and it pop out message "java.sql.SQLException: No specified for parameter 5"; what this mean...can you help me sir to fix the error.

I have combobox which name is monitorlocation that contains a value of Laboratory A,Laboratory B, Laboratory C, Laboratory D, Laboratory E, Library. The monitorlocation is for when i save a data i chose in value of combobox for me to save it in different place because the monitor are separated in several laboratory.

this is my code for connecting in database:

```
import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import net.proteanit.sql.DbUtils;

public class Monitors extends javax.swing.JFrame {

 public Connection con;
PreparedStatement pst=null;

public Monitors() {
    initComponents();
    try {
                      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                    con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/computerinventorysystem","root","");
   Update_tableA();
               Update_tableB();//*Update the data of table in xampp to the java jtable*//
                Update_tableC();//*Update the data of table in xampp to the java jtable*//
                Update_tableD();//*Update the data of table in xampp to the java jtable*//
                Update_tableE();//*Update the data of table in xampp to the java jtable*//
                Update_tableLib();//*Update the data of table in xampp to the java jtable*//


    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    }
```

code Updating the xampp table or to the java jtable:

```
 private void Update_tableA(){
try{
String sql = "select * from monitor_la";
pst=con.prepareStatement(sql);
ResultSet rs=pst.executeQuery();
monitor_A.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));

}catch(Exception e){
}

}
private void Update_tableB(){
try{
String sql = "select * from monitor_lb";
pst=con.prepareStatement(sql);
ResultSet rs=pst.executeQuery();
monitor_B.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));

}catch(Exception e){
}

}
private void Update_tableC(){
try{
String sql = "select * from monitor_lc";
pst=con.prepareStatement(sql);
ResultSet rs=pst.executeQuery();
monitor_C.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));

}catch(Exception e){
}

}
private void Update_tableD(){
try{
String sql = "select * from monitor_ld";
pst=con.prepareStatement(sql);
ResultSet rs=pst.executeQuery();
monitor_D.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));

}catch(Exception e){
}

}
private void Update_tableE(){
try{
String sql = "select * from monitor_le";
pst=con.prepareStatement(sql);
ResultSet rs=pst.executeQuery();
monitor_E.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));

}catch(Exception e){
}

}
private void Update_tableLib(){
try{
String sql = "select * from monitor_library";
pst=con.prepareStatement(sql);
ResultSet rs=pst.executeQuery();
monitor_library.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));

}catch(Exception e){
}

}
```

And for saving the data in database:

```
   private void cmdSaveActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
   if (monitorSN.getText().equals("") || monitorM.getText().equals("") ||        monitorB.getText().equals("") || monitorSS.getText().equals("")){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Required to fill all the boxes!!!");
 } else if (monitorlocation.getSelectedItem().equals("Laboratory A")){
      String sql= "Insert Into monitor_la (SerialNumber,model,brand,ScreenSize) values  (?,?,?,?)";

      try {
                      pst=con.prepareStatement(sql);

       pst.setString(1, monitorSN.getText());
        pst.setString(2, monitorM.getText());
         pst.setString(3, monitorB.getText());
          pst.setString(4, monitorSS.getText());
            pst.execute();
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Data Saved!");
      } catch (Exception e) {
      }Update_tableA();

  }else if (monitorlocation.getSelectedItem().equals("Laboratory B")){
      String sql= "Insert Into monitor_lb (SerialNumber,model,brand,ScreenSize) values (?,?,?,?)";
     try {
                pst=con.prepareStatement(sql);

       pst.setString(1, monitorSN.getText());
        pst.setString(2, monitorM.getText());
         pst.setString(3, monitorB.getText());
          pst.setString(4, monitorSS.getText());

             pst.execute();
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Data Saved!");


     } catch (Exception e) {
     }Update_tableB();
  }else if (monitorlocation.getSelectedItem().equals("Laboratory C")){
      String sql= "Insert Into monitor_lc (SerialNumber,model,brand,ScreenSize) values (?,?,?,?)";
      try {
         pst=con.prepareStatement(sql);

       pst.setString(1, monitorSN.getText());
        pst.setString(2, monitorM.getText());
         pst.setString(3, monitorB.getText());
          pst.setString(4, monitorSS.getText());

             pst.execute();
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Data Saved!");

     } catch (Exception e) {
     }Update_tableC();
 }                                       
 else if (monitorlocation.getSelectedItem().equals("Laboratory D")){
      String sql= "Insert Into monitor_ld (SerialNumber,model,brand,ScreenSize) values  (?,?,?,?)";
      try {
           pst=con.prepareStatement(sql);

       pst.setString(1, monitorSN.getText());
        pst.setString(2, monitorM.getText());
         pst.setString(3, monitorB.getText());
          pst.setString(4, monitorSS.getText());

             pst.execute();
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Data Saved!");
     } catch (Exception e) {
     }Update_tableD();
  }else if (monitorlocation.getSelectedItem().equals("Laboratory E")){
      String sql= "Insert Into monitor_le (SerialNumber,model,brand,ScreenSize) values   (?,?,?,?)";
      try {
            pst=con.prepareStatement(sql);

       pst.setString(1, monitorSN.getText());
        pst.setString(2, monitorM.getText());
         pst.setString(3, monitorB.getText());
          pst.setString(4, monitorSS.getText());

             pst.execute();
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Data Saved!");
     } catch (Exception e) {
     }Update_tableE();
    }else if (monitorlocation.getSelectedItem().equals("Library")){
      String sql= "Insert Into monitor_library (SerialNumber,model,brand,ScreenSize)    values (?,?,?,?)";
      try {
               pst=con.prepareStatement(sql);

       pst.setString(1, monitorSN.getText());
        pst.setString(2, monitorM.getText());
         pst.setString(3, monitorB.getText());
          pst.setString(4, monitorSS.getText());

             pst.executeUpdate();
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Data Saved!");
     } catch (Exception e) {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
     }Update_tableLib();
}
}
```

And for update, I only try to update the values in SubJtabbedPane Laboratory A and this is the code for it:

```
private void cmdUpdateActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          

    try {
        String sql = "update monitor_la set SerialNumber=? ,model=?,brand= ? ,ScreenSize= ? where SerialNumber=? where SerialNumber=?";
   pst=con.prepareStatement(sql);
   pst.setString(1, monitorSN.getText());
    pst.setString(2, monitorM.getText());
     pst.setString(3, monitorB.getText());
      pst.setString(4, monitorSS.getText());


   pst.execute();

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Updated");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
  Update_tableA();

}
```

then it will gave me an error out and that is "java.sql.SQLException: No specified for parameter 5"

Comment: sir maheswaran ravisankar i tried to set 5 bind variable and its look like this "pst.setString(5,"" );" and its not working how can i properly set it

Answer (score 1):

You have a mistake in query of method `cmdUpdateActionPerformed()` , you are not setting the parameter for where clause  `SerialNumber  ?`

And the reason for the exception `"java.sql.SQLException: No specified for parameter 5"`

```
SerialNumber=? ,model=?,brand= ? ,ScreenSize= ?  where SerialNumber=? <-- missing param for this last binder
```

You are setting 4 values for those four params. But not supplying for where clause.

and also repeated  `where SerialNumber=?`

```
....ScreenSize= ? where SerialNumber=? where SerialNumber=?"
```

change it to

```
.... ScreenSize= ? where SerialNumber=?"
```

Get rid of that extra where.